# How to substring a string in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string in SQL like

> INF/000079160100/P - (**34**) cases NET BANKING

I want to read a string in bold. 
How to read that string using substring function.

```
select 'INF/000079160153/P- (539) cases NET BANKING',Substring('INF/000079160153/P- (539) cases NET BANKING', CHARINDEX('(', 'INF/000079160153/P- (539) cases NET BANKING',(SELECT CHARINDEX('/', 'INF/000079160153/P- (539) cases NET BANKING')+1))+1,6)
```

This is gives me 539) c but i want to read only to the closing bracket.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 'INF/000079160153/P- (539) cases NET BANKING',
Substring('INF/000079160153/P- (539) cases NET BANKING', 
  CHARINDEX('(', 'INF/000079160153/P- (539) cases NET BANKING',(SELECT CHARINDEX('/', 'INF/000079160153/P- (539) cases NET BANKING')+1))+1,
  CHARINDEX(')', 'INF/000079160153/P- (539) cases NET BANKING')-CHARINDEX('(', 'INF/000079160153/P- (539) cases NET BANKING')-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have hardcoded length of `SUBSTRING` function - (... , 6) ...)
In query you need to count length as difference between index of `'('` character and `')'` character

```
DECLARE @Test AS NVARCHAR(200) = 'INF/000079160153/P- (539) cases NET BANKING'
SELECT @Test
, SUBSTRING(@Test
        , CHARINDEX('(', @Test,CHARINDEX('/', @Test)) + 1
        , CHARINDEX(')', @Test,CHARINDEX('/', @Test)) - (CHARINDEX('(', @Test,CHARINDEX('/', @Test)) + 1))
```